# How much space needed in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php to insert data to my mysql DB, everyday I insert from 100 to 1000 rows of data. Does the space in the DB risk to finish and data won't be able to be inserted anymore?

Comment: there are a few limits you could encounter but as you don't provide the most basic of information no one can answer this question.

Comment: Of course there's a risk. Disk space isn't infinite, so eventually you could fill the disk. How quickly depends on how big each row is, and how much disk space you have.

Comment: You did not provide information as to the size of your disk and how large the rows are that are being inserted on daily basis are...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The space in your DB is determined by your hosting provider. I believe when you're getting close to the limit, you will be informed by your host.

Comment: i think what the op means is locally, how much data can mysql contain before it gets full, not the hosting company's mysql provision

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought otherwise. The OP didn't state that anyway.

Comment: Glad I was able to answer your question @webtuto